# Excel's Worksheet Change event not firing unless cell is manually changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that updates cell 'B' with the price of bitcoin from the web (Powerquery) at intervals. The idea is that when the cell updates with a new price, I am supposed to take the new price and store it in another cell, 'G'. Then, wait for the price change again in cell 'B' to store it in a new blank cell. I have made a worksheet_change code that detects cell 'B' changes and stores the change in another column. But this only works when cell 'A' is changed manually, not when updated from the web. How can I make it work even for updates from the web? Code is as below:

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Range("B2").Address Then

              
Call Update_Price

End If


End Sub



Private Sub Update_Price()


Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select

ActiveCell = Cells(2, 2)


End Sub`
```

Comment: Is B2 a formula?  If so then you will need to use a worksheet_calculate event.

Comment: B2 IS NOT A FORMULA BUT RATHER A LINK TO THE WEB VIA POWERQUERY

Comment: @ScottCraner worksheet_calculate worked, thanks.